# Get URLs value from the path of ALAsset Library

Tags: ios, url, alassetslibrary

I have a NSMutableArray where i get this value of images.

```
 <__NSArrayM 0x14259390>(ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=6C7406FE-D0A8-4625-ABBA-1C2D758E0B54&ext=JPG)
```

Now I have to get `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=6C7406FE-D0A8-4625-ABBA-1C2D758E0B54&ext=JPG` this URL value from this String.And I am doing this piece of code

```
 for (int i = 0; i < self.selectedPhotos.count; i++) {

    NSString *object = [self.selectedPhotos objectAtIndex:i] ;

    NSArray *details = [object componentsSeparatedByString:@"URLs"];

    self.msg = [details lastObject];

}
```

But in details array i am getting this error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ALAsset componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ba93f20'`
Can anyone give me solution please How can i get this URL from this whole path.
Thanks a Lot.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct, if it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this inside the for loop:

```
ALAsset *object = [self.selectedPhotos objectAtIndex:i] ;

ALAssetRepresentation *rep = object.defaultRepresentation;

self.msg = rep.url.absoluteString;
```